# finding the docker container ip for adding wait

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker compose file with 2 containers to bring up. I want to wait for DB container to be up before i start my web server container.

i have a script that can wait until a given host:port is accessbile. my current docker file looks like:

```
version: '3'

    services:
      db:
        image: <image repo url>
        ports:
          - "5500:5500"

      web:
        image: <image repo url>
        ports:
         - "7001:7001"
```

My plan is to modify web image and have the wait script to be the first thing before i proceed to bring it up.

However, the problem I am stuck is on how would i know the ip of the db container from the web container to test as ping?

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
CONTAINER_ID=`docker-compose ps -q web`
docker inspect -f '{{range .NetworkSettings.Networks} }{{.IPAddress}}{{end}}' $CONTAINER_ID
```

This way you can get the container ID and then the IP.

I hope it helps,